# Never ending Ticker in Golang works only 2 times

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a channel with never ending ticker, but it works only 2 times.

Could you help me to understand where is the problem?

Code:

```
package main 

import (
"fmt"
"time"
) 

var mark = [2]float64{8.9876, 762.098568}

func tick(out chan <- [2]float64){

    c := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond *500)
    for range c.C{
        out <- mark
    }
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Start")

    md := make(chan [2]float64)
    go tick(md)

    for range <-md{
        fmt.Println(<-md)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start
[8.9876 762.098568]
[8.9876 762.098568]
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/P2FaUwbW-3

Comment: This is one of the first minimal, complete, and verifiable examples I've ever seen from a new user. Great question moneyzmey, keep it up, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
for range <-md{
```

is not the same as:

```
for range md{
```

The latter ranges over the channel (what you want), while the former ranges over *the value received from the channel when the loop starts*, which happens to be a two-element array, hence the two executions. You're also ignoring the value received from the channel in the `for` statement, and reading from it *again* in the loop body, ignoring every other message on the channel (though this makes no difference in the example, since every value is identical, it would make a significant difference in practice). What you really want is:

```
for foo := range md{
    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

Here's a working version of your playground example, slightly modified to avoid "program took too long" errors because in its current form it never stops: https://play.golang.org/p/RSUJFvluU5